# I am trying for activity animation from the mid (zoom in and zoom out)?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I was searching for zoom in and zoom out activity animation between activites.

I didn't get a proper idea for xml style, and can we achieve it with .

Do you guys have any idea for doing this or any sample code links, Please share.

Like the activity animation used in [Feedly]- Android application

Answer (score 0):

From android API demo, copy res/anim folder into your Application. & use:

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_out,R.anim.fade_in);
```